# How to debug a STM32 MCU Discovery board at higher rates?

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, embedded, debugging, probe

I have a STM32H735G-DK Discovery board, and can debug it with gdb (or vscode and cortex-debug).  However, it is very slow - hitting `s` in gdb can take several seconds.

Is there a way to speed this up? If I buy a [Segger EDU Probe](https://www.segger.com/products/debug-probes/j-link/models/j-link-edu/), will stepping/debugging go faster? Besides the probe itself, what connectors or cables do I need to debug this board (and also a Nucleo F446RE, which I have as well)?

---

## Update

Even under normal conditions, gdb `s` seems to take at least a second per line and often much more.

I launch from command line:

```
(st-util &) && sleep 1 && gdb-multiarch -q -ex "target remote :4242" firmware.elf
```

Here are versions:

```
$ gdb-multiarch --version
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 12.1-0ubuntu1~22.04) 12.1
Copyright (C) 2022 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

$ st-util --version
v1.7.0
```

I do not use openocd.

The problem occurs both when launching gdb from command line and from vscode cortex debug.

Comment: I am an old fogey. So I know how things were done back in the day. We could use gdb (or other debug hooks into the code) but this modifies the code that is running, which can impact its timing, and it is, as you say, slow. So we bought devices called MSOs, bond-out ICEs, and logic analyzers and downloaded the actual code. It's not difficult to instrument the code so that you run just the portions you want to test and it isn't difficult to add code to create a 'trigger' for a scope to use. If there are newer/better ways to run code at full speed and test the actual code, I'm not aware of them.

Comment: (I am aware of and own ICE systems that no longer use bond-out chips, though. They aren't quite as good, my opinion, as the older bond-outs which provided very very wide traces at full clock speed. But that might be a reasonable approach. It's what I also use more of, now.) Why don't you call a local FAE and ask for help?

Comment: I usually debug in cubeIDE (mostly nucleo boards) and stepping the code is much faster than one line per sec. You can also run until next breakpoint with same delay. I am not sure what is difference in gdb.

Comment: It depends on many factors, but generally `s` should be fast. It may be slow, for example, if you add huge array to the watch window. Then debugger every time read lot of memory and it takes time. Under normal condition it shold be fast. If you feel, that you do everything under normal condition, but it is slow, then we will need more ifnormation like if you st-link gdb, openocd, their versions, vscode launch.json, other related configs, ....

Comment: @Misaz Thanks, updated.